# user dissapered after connection to GNU Screen

Tags: linux, ssh, gnu-screen

After the user logged in and before he ran the `GNU Screen`,

```
[root@15inch ~]# w
 11:45:17 up  3:44,  2 users,  load average: 0,00, 0,02, 0,00
USER     TTY        LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
user  pts/2     09:42    7.00s  0.03s  0.03s -bash
[root@15inch ~]# who
user  pts/2        2018-08-31 09:42 (192.168.1.136)
[root@15inch ~]#
```

but after it run `GNU Screen` I saw nothing:

```
[root@15inch ~]# w
[root@15inch ~]# who
[root@15inch ~]#
```

only `who --all` shows something:

```
# who --all
           system boot  Aug 31 08:01
LOGIN      tty1         Aug 31 08:01               548 id=tty1
           pts/2        Aug 31 09:42              3068 id=ts/2  term=0 exit=0
```

the `pts/2` is pseudo TTY that was created after his login via `ssh`.
But when I try to send message to him:

```
[root@15inch ~]# write user pts/2
write: user is not logged in on pts/2
```

only direct usage of pts/2 works:

```
[root@15inch ~]# echo "HI" > /dev/pts/2 
[root@15inch ~]#
```

is this expected behavior? Why `GNU Screen` hide this user from  system utils?

Comment: Is the user actually still logged in?  If you exit `screen` can you message them?

Comment: @EricRenouf yes, use still logined in. And if user detach GNU screen, `w` / `who` starts to `see` him. If he attach screen session again `screen -rd` then he again "disapper".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a legitimate feature, although I don't *exactly* know the original reason for it. I would guess that Screen removes the 'outer' tty from utmp because it's no longer relevant – as long as you're "attached", for most intents and purposes you're not really interacting with the 'outer' tty.

Normally it doesn't cause problems because Screen **should add utmp entries for each *inner* pty** (corresponding to each screen window). You should be seeing entries with hostnames like "`:S.0`" or "`<originalhost>:S.0`" in the *who -a* output.

If this does not happen, make sure the window is marked as "logged in"; try <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd><kbd>Shift+L</kbd> to toggle the login state. (The default state is set using **`deflogin on`** in ~/.screenrc or the system-wide screenrc.)